# How do you write a setup method that is executed just once for a test file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I would like to have a method that runs once per file rather than once per test. I've seen some references to a "before" method, but doesnt appear to work with MiniTest. Ideally, something like this:

```
class MyTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
   before do
      # Executes once per file
   end

   setup do
      # Executes once per test
   end

   # Tests go here
end
```

Comment: It would be nice to have a `teardown` solution as well for a *once for a test file* situation.

Answer (score 4):

**Before** is used when you are using spec dsl for minitest, it is equivalent to **setup**.
You can use **setup**, if you use setup in your test_helper.rb file it 'll be executed once before all tests.

setup can also be declared in test classes. Use setup, place a flag and update the flag on first time.

```
x = 0
setup do
  if x == 0
    x = x + 1
    puts "Incremented in x = #{x}"
  end
end
```

OR

```
setup_executed = false
setup do
  unless setup_executed
    #code goes here
    setup_executed = true
  end
end
```

Comment: `setup` method inside ActiveSupport::TestCase class is executed before each test method/call again. Not once per class.

Comment: @Foton is right, setup is not the correct answer for this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can add your code outside the class definition.

```
  # Executes once per file
  puts "Executed once"

  class MyTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

     setup do
        # Executes once per test
     end

     # Tests go here
  end
```

You can also add your code inside the class definition, but outside of any method:

```
  class MyTest #< ActiveSupport::TestCase
    # Executes once per Testclass
     puts "Executed once"

     setup do
        # Executes once per test
     end

     # Tests go here
  end
```

Comment: Also, in order for database records to persist from one test to another, you'll probably need to disable "transaction fixtures" (wrapping all database operations in a transaction that gets rolled back after the test case) for the test file where you want to do this.